# Explanation of SQL code

Tags: sql

Can anyone explain to me what the following code does? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) this code joins Subscribers table records with Relatiws table records where Subscribers table phone number is equals to Relatives table column 'subscriber' value.
2)Then this code joins resulting table records from first step with Activities table records where Relatives table column 'FamilyMember' value is equal to Activities table column 'Subscriber' value.

Resulting table from step two has 10 columns

1 PhoneNumber
2 Name
3 SubscriptionDate
4 Subscriber
5 FamilyMember
6 ID
7 Subscriber
8 Date
9 Type
10 Content

3)then this code selects column 'Contents' values from resulting table from second step where name is 'Ringo Star' and type is 'Message received'.